# Add two numbers together using a class

Tags: java, oop, class

I am a beginner to object oriented programming and I want to write simple code to add two numbers together using an object. Here is my main part:

```
package main;
public class Main {
 test sum = new test();
 System.out.println("sum="+sum.c);
}
```

And here is my class:

```
package main;
public class test {

public int c;

public test() {
    int a = 1;
    int b = 1;
    int c = a + b;
}

public int c() {
    return c();
}
}
```

Based on my understanding, it should return 2, but it returns 0. Am I doing anything wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're shadowing the `c` attribute in the method using a local variable with the same name `c`. Just remove the declaration of the variable:

```
public test() {
    int a = 1;
    int b = 1;
    c = a + b;
}
```

Also, in your `c()` method you should return the variable, not the method:

```
public int c() {
    return c;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Some issues:

- you assign `int c = a + b;` but you are redeclaring the variable so it shadows the instance variables (which remains `0`), it should be `c = a + b`
- the function `c()` is useless and rather dangerous since it invokes it self (endless recursion: `StackOverflowException`)
- classes should be named uppercase (`Test` not `test`)

Comment: Also, packages are typically beneath the writer's domain reversed, as in  `package com.example` instead of `package main`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
public class Test {

    int a = 1;
    int b = 1;
    int c = a + b;

    public int getC() {
        return c;
    }
}
```

And this:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
         Test sum = new Test();
         System.out.println("Sum = " + sum.getC());
    }
}
```

Your problem is that your integers are in a method meaning they are only available in that method. Also to print the integer out you have to call it like you would call a method with ()'s.

Comment: This doesn't explain what the OP did wrong. SO is not a givemetehcodz service.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please also read the FAQ if you haven't yet.

Comment: I have since change my downvote to an upvote ecause you fixed your post.

Comment: Thanks Cole. I have now read the FAQ I'll try not to make anymore mistakes like this.